# setting seed number for ergm in statnet R

Tags: r, random-seed, statnet

I want to set the seed number in `ergm`, so that my network analysis is reproducible, but when I run

```r
main_sup <- ergm(supnet ~ edges + nodefactor("work") + 
                     nodefactor("income") + nodefactor("edu") + 
                     nodefactor("religious") + nodefactor("gender") + 
                     nodecov("age") + edgecov(kin_sup,"kinweight"), 
                 control.ergm(seed = 567))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in eval(e, parent.frame()) : object 'name' not found'
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I forgot to name the `control` argument, as in:

```r
control = control.ergm(seed = 567)
```